# Why does `&value.into_something()` still result in a moved value?

Tags: rust

I'm struggling to see how this transfers ownership. Here is my code:

```
let res = screenshot::take_screenshot(0);
let file = File::open("test.png").expect("Failed to open file");

let encoder = PNGEncoder::new(file);
encoder.encode(&res.into_raw(), 
               res.width(),
               res.height(),
               ColorType::RGBA(0)
);
```

`screenshot::take_screenshot` is a function that returns an `ImageBuffer<Rgba<u8>, Vec<u8>>`. Here is the compiler error I'm getting:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `res`
  --> src/main.rs:21:37
   |
21 |     encoder.encode(&res.into_raw(), res.width(), res.height(), ColorType::RGBA(0));
   |                     ---             ^^^ value used here after move
   |                     |
   |                     value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because `res` has type `image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgba<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `res`
  --> src/main.rs:21:50
   |
21 |     encoder.encode(&res.into_raw(), res.width(), res.height(), ColorType::RGBA(0));
   |                     --- value moved here         ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `res` has type `image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgba<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I am trying to pass a slice, which I believe is a reference of the vector, is it not? This would imply ownership is not passed, and the vector isn't moved. I know I'm doing something wrong and it's likely something simple.

Comment: Better have a look at [into_raw](https://docs.rs/image/0.18.0/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.into_raw). Also relevant is that, by convention, methods with the `into_` prefix consume the original value.

Comment: Right, okay yeah I feel I should have noticed that. Wouldn't that simply transfer ownership of the underlying container though? Not the image struct itself? Or am I misunderstanding things?

Comment: No, not really. If a method takes `self`, the whole value will be moved, regardless of what is returned.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks for the help! I feel like I'm slowly getting there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply an operator precedence issue: methods apply before the reference operator `&`:

```
&(res.into_raw()) // This
(&res).into_raw() // Not this
```

Calling [`into_raw`](https://docs.rs/image/0.18.0/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.into_raw) takes ownership and the value is gone.

You could do something like this:

```
let w = res.width();
let h = res.height();
let r = res.into_raw();
encoder.encode(&r, w, h, ColorType::RGBA(0));
```

It's likely there's something nicer, but you haven't provided a [MCVE](/help/mcve) so it's hard to iterate on a solution. Blindly guessing from the docs, it looks like this should work:

```
extern crate image;

use image::{png::PNGEncoder, ColorType, ImageBuffer, Rgba};
use std::io;

fn repro<W: io::Write>(res: ImageBuffer<Rgba<u8>, Vec<u8>>, file: W) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let encoder = PNGEncoder::new(file);
    encoder.encode(&res, res.width(), res.height(), ColorType::RGBA(0))
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Right, okay. That mkaes sense, probably should pay attention to the name of functions.
Could you point me in the right direction for a solution to this? It seems weird to have to copy the underlying container which is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: Thanks, that got it. And I apologize, I thought this would be enough. Encoder is not something I wrote. It comes from the `image` crate from the Piston game engine.

Comment: If you say that `res` is an `ImageBuffer`, how about just calling [`save`](https://docs.rs/image/0.18.0/image/struct.ImageBuffer.html#method.save)?

Comment: I'm basically creating a program for taking screenshots and automatically uploading them/copying the uploaded link the clipboard. Often the user might not even want to save it to disk, so there's more to do with the data than just write it to disk unfortunately.